# HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httprequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying use HttpWebRequest, and my BeginGetRequestStream works but it never enters the BeginGetResponse function and i have no idea why.. i've searched for a couple of hours and have not found a solution that works

```
    public void Initialize(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        if(_isCloud)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_cloudMappingServer + "/Mapping/GetAllCentralPoints");

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ReleaseReadCallback), request);

            // Instruct the thread to wait until we resume it
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            _waitHandle.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            using (Stream postStream = httpRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    string queryString = string.Empty;
                    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
                    memStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    memStream.Position = 0;

                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
                    memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                    postStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                }
            }

            httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReleaseResponseCallback), httpRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var test = ex;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest responseRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        string responseString = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)responseRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

                    try
                    {
                        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                        List<CentralPointViewModel> _allCentralPointViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CentralPointViewModel>>(responseString, settings);
                    }
                    catch (JsonReaderException)
                    {
                        responseString = responseString.Replace('\"'.ToString(), string.Empty);
                        string[] responseArray = responseString.Split(';');
                    }
                    catch (JsonSerializationException)
                    {
                        responseString = responseString.Replace('\"'.ToString(), string.Empty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

It never enters the ReleaseResponseCallback function! I am able to make my server call but the response never reaches me or I am not properly receiving it.. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you have checked whether there's an exception in the method ReleaseReadCallback. Currently you have an empty catch, that swallows any exceptions.

Comment: @DonJayamanne I actually made a typo! It goes into ReleaseReadCallback and executes fine, never entering the catch, then executes my request properly. I never get the response from my request - it never enters ReleaseResponseCallback